# Resale of a House with Estate Rentcharge

Tags: united-kingdom, first-time-home-buyer, home, contracts, house-sale

Made an offer on a c. 40 yr. old *freehold* house in London. Had offer accepted.
When going through the docs as part of pre sign-off due-dilligence, turned out there is a 300 GBP / year Estate Rentcharge with draconian remedies like:

- Right of re-entry to take stuff.
- Grant lease of the house/land.
- Sale or mortgage of the house/land.

**Two questions:**

- **Does this mean the house is unsellable?**
- **If I get these remedies removed, though rentcharge fee remains, does the house become normal and easily sellable again?**

Comment: Are you using a solicitor and what have they said about it?

Comment: When was the house built?

Answer (score 2):

Run don't walk.

https://wslaw.co.uk/insight/rentcharges-a-plague-on-your-houses/

https://www.eversheds-sutherland.com/global/en/what/articles/index.page?ArticleID=en/Litigation_Support/rentcharges

https://www.daviesandpartners.com/news-events/353-avoiding-the-rentcharge-scam

https://www.bbc.com/news/business-50519066

https://www.luptonfawcett.com/about-us/blog/how-avoid-rentcharge-scam/

..........

Comment: I think this answers the first question. Now only the second one remains; in this particular case there is little risk of fee increase and I think lenders are primarily concerned about the crazy remedies.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger , greets, I was just wondering, are you new to the UK perhaps from overseas or ...?  there is Not A Chance you can get such remedies removed from a rentcharge covenant.  Note too that if you "buy it out" if I'm not mistaken that only happens if you can get everyone in the estate/group to agree.